# C struct pointer Seg.fault when malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to implement the ringbuffer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/827749 and the only code I've added is a main that looks like this.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    circular_buffer *my_buff;
    cb_init(my_buff, 16, sizeof(char));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I get a SIGSEV (Segmentation fault) error as soon as I try to run this code though. By the looks of it it happens on the first row in cb_init() where malloc() is called.

Comment: What debugging have you attempted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `my_buff`

At the moment you're passing an uninitialised pointer into `cb_init` which is then dereferenced.

But I'm sure you must have realised this because I'm sure you will have tried running the code in a debugger...

Comment: I did try to run it in the Netbeans debugger but I don't really know what to make of all the info. But I totally see what you mean, and it's so obvious when you say it. Thanks!