# How to allocate tempoarary small memory segments in C

Tags: c, memory, pointers, buffer

I'm trying to use a circular buffer like the one mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/827749

When I need to push and pop things to the buffer I find myself doing something like this all the time:

```
int data;
int *data_ptr = &data;
cb_pop(spi_buffer, data_ptr);
```

Is this the best (probably not) way to do this? How would you do it?

Thanks

Comment: `int data; cb_pop(buffer, &data);` works just as well. No problem with that as long as you understand that `data` is on the current function's stack and goes away as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why won't you just do:

```
int data;
cb_pop(spi_buffer, &data);
```

the creation of another pointer variable is redundant.

Comment: Prolly beacause I suck at C =)