# Free a single element from a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

I have a problem in a C program: I would like to free the first element from a dynamic array but I don't know if it is possible nor how I could do it.
For instance if I allocate an array A made of 10 integers like this:

```
int *A;
A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

is it possible to free the first position of the array? In which way?
I must optimize the program so I can't do some `memcpy` ignoring the first element or similar stuff because it would be a slowdown.

Comment: you want to free the memory of the first array element?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: You cannot free just part of an allocated block. Don't worry about micro optimizations- just skip the first element the simple way.

Comment: What is your goal exactly?

Comment: I built a queue and it is built on a dinamic array because I don't know how much is the maximum of the elements in the queue. So when I reach the size limit I use 'realloc' function making it bigger. When I dequeue an element I would like to free that part of the memory because probably there will be a lot of memory lost instead.

Comment: Then your design is not good enough. Either use a ring buffer or a linked list.

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way.  Do a little more research on how queues can be implemented and how you can re-use the space at the beginning of the array by wrapping around.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I can't use the space at the beginning becuase when the queue is full I reallocate memory beacause I don't know how much space I need

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do you mean with ring buffer?

Comment: @g.delv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827691/how-do-you-implement-a-circular-buffer-in-c

Comment: Your question is about freeing elements at the beginning.  Instead of freeing them, you should be recycling them.  Do some research on ring buffers as Eugene Sh. mentioned; that should get you started.

Comment: Ok thank you very much guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate a chuck of memory, you can't deallocate a part of it.  It has to be the whole chunk.  More specifically, you can only pass to `free` exactly what was returned by `malloc` / `calloc` / `realloc`.

What you can do is use `realloc` to resize a memory region, however this is not something you want to do too frequently as it can affect performance.  A good rule is to double the size when you want to expand and half the size when you want to contract.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "free" a single portion of an allocated memory block.
If you want to "ignore" the first element, you could use A+1 which points to the second element.