# Circular scroll array

Tags: c

I don't post the code because I don't know how to write it, I have an array of integers and a number 'k' entered by the user. What the program has to do is translate the elements of the array k positions forward. I don't know how to do when the last elements come out of the array while they should be positioned between the first cells. A sort of circular movement of values. Which from the end return to the beginning of the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you implement a circular buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827691/how-do-you-implement-a-circular-buffer-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're at index i in an array, `(i + k) mod array_length` will give you circular motion. For example, moving two spots forward in the middle of a 3-length array:

```
[a b c] 
   ^ i = 1

[a b c] ?
        ^ i = (1 + 2) mod 3

[a b c]
 ^ i = 3 mod 3 = 0
```

Depending on how you implement your solution you may want to check if `k` and `array_length` are coprime. If they aren't you could end up going around the array on the same loop and not cover every element.