# Remove an array from a setlist if count above x

Tags: c++

I am currently using an `std::set<uintptr_t> list` to store unique pointers in it. This list gets bigger with the time and when this list reaches x amount of entries it should delete the first entry, the other entries should move down one and make room for a new entry.

For example:

```
if (list.count >= 20)
{
    list.remove[0]; //remove the first entry from the list?
}
```

I know this code doesn't work but just for the logic so you know what I mean. Also the first entry would be empty then, would it be possible to move all other entries one down so the [0] entry isn't empty anymore?

Comment: [`std::set::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase)

Comment: Why are you using `uintptr_t` for pointers? Pointers to what? Why aren't you using actual pointers instead of an *integer* type (`uintptr_t` is an integer type, large enough to also hold pointer values)? That has a definite bad smell about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude uintptr_t is an unsigned integer type that is capable of storing a data pointer. Which typically means that it's the same size as a pointer which is perfect for what I am doing. Regarding this question it doesn't matter what type it is.

Comment: a set is not an array, hence it is not quite clear what you mean with "should move down one and make room for a new entry."

Comment: also "the first entry would be empty then", no the first entry would be removed, and the second element is the new first

Comment: frankly your question seems to be driven by some wrong assumptions. I suggest you to write the code and see what actually happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215557/how-do-i-implement-a-circular-list-ring-buffer-in-c Is it what you want to do ?

Comment: If you have a pointer, use a pointer. That makes the code clear, readable, understandable and maintainable. It also doesn't sidestep type-checking which is an important part of making sure that the code builds as expected and does what it's supposed to do. There must be a reason you picked `uintptr_t`, what is that reason? What problem did that solve for you? Perhaps it's not the only solution? Perhaps there are better and more "C++-ish" solutions that can work *with* the type-system rather than site-stepping it? If I saw that as your teacher or mentor or colleague I would fail it.

Comment: And I'm sorry for nagging about it, but it's really an important issue. Good code leads to good programs. Shortcuts and being "smart" usually leads to the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the iterator of your first element in your list with list.begin()

```
if (list.count >= 20)
{
    list.erase(list.begin()); //remove the first entry from the list
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this won't compile. `[]` -> `()`

Comment: edit in code list.erase(list.begin()) thx 
@463035818_is_not_a_number